# scala match on iteration, weird compiler error

Tags: scala

This small piece of scala code when compiled 
it gives a strange error.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val rs = new ListBuffer[String]()
    val ns = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()

    "A very long string".split("\\ ") foreach { word =>

        word match {
            case x if x.length() > 7  => ns += x -> "="
            case _ =>   rs += word 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
test.scala:11: error: type arguments [String,Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with PartialFunction[String with Int,String] with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[String,Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with PartialFunction[String with Int,String] with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[String,Equals]]{def seq: Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with PartialFunction[String with Int,String]}] do not conform to trait Subtractable's type parameter bounds [A,+Repr <: scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[A,Repr]]
    "A very long string".split("\\ ") foreach { word =>
                                              ^
one error found
```

Any hints?

Comment: Which Scala version are you using? It compiles fine on http://rextester.com/l/scala_online_compiler

Comment: scalac -version  is 2.12.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to the fact that your pattern match returns a lengthy compound type:

```
[String,Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with PartialFunction[String with Int,String] with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[String,Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with PartialFunction[String with Int,String] with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[String,Equals]]{def seq: Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with PartialFunction[String with Int,String]}]
```

Where one of the types in the linearization is `Subtractable[String, Iterable[Serializable]]` which your type doesn't conform to it's type constraint:

```
trait Subtractable[A, +Repr <: Subtractable[A, Repr]
```

To fix this, help the compiler out with type annotation on `foreach`:

```
"A very long string"
  .split("\\")
  .foreach[Unit] {
  case x if x.length() > 7 => ns += x -> "="
  case word => rs += word
}
```

As a side note, perhaps you can find the following implementation helpful:

```
val (largerThanSeven, smallerThanSeven) = "A very long string"
  .split("\\")
  .partition(_.length > 7)

val largerThanSevenMap = largerThanSeven.map(_ -> "=").toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
ns += x -> "="
```

I guess the intention is to put the key `x` and the value `"="` into the mutable map.

This will compile if changed to

```
ns(x) = "="
```

The problem is that there are implicits involved into conversions with `->` and the types are inferred weirdly into the monstrous string in the error message.

Comment: Indeed it compiles